# Limiting image transform totals in queue?

Tags: database, image-transforms, queue

In order to serve webp images where possible, and different sizes for different screens etc, I created a bunch of image transforms over the weekend - forgetting just how many images we have in the Assets folder.

Now, inevitably as tasks time out, I'm faced with the queue running tasks requiring 10k+ transforms before moving to the next task. Is there a way to limit how many transforms can count as an individual task in the queue? Or split them in some other way to not end up with endless tasks that never complete?

If I use the console verbose mode, I am given messages repeating

````
The SQL being executed was: UPDATE `queue_hashed` SET `fail`=1, `dateFailed`='2022-02-07 15:26:29', `error`='The process \"\'/usr/bin/php7.4\' \'craft\' \'queue/exec\' \'53140\' \'300\' \'1\' \'683652\' \'--color=1\'\" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.' WHERE `id`='53140'```
````